# why apache directing request diffirently for chrome?

Tags: apache

in chrome when I type simply

> "http://localhost:81"

request directed to "http://mypersonalweb.com/home"

in mozilla I type

> "http://localhost:81"

this time, localhost:81 page open with phpinfo() content.. how I cant find where are these configurations set ?

Comment: did you check "DirectoryIndex" of http.conf file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your httpd.conf file and go to line 'DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"'(its for my instance.) Whatever directory writes here there must be a file contains

> phpinfo();

function in it. so you need to find this file in httpd.conf file in the line of "DirectoryIndex"
change it whatever you want to begin your application.